# Org code block receives table without header

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm trying to send an Org table as a lisp object to a code block for further processing with an elisp function. For testing I set up two code blocks, one that generates the table and another that receives the table.

The first block works fine:

```
#+NAME: from-r
#+BEGIN_SRC R :results value :colnames yes
  q <- data.frame(something1 = c("a", "b", "c"), something2 = c(1, 5, 100))
  q
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: from-r
| something1 | something2 |
|------------+------------|
| a          |          1 |
| b          |          5 |
| c          |        100 |
```

But the second block is not receiving the whole table!

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var the-table=from-r :results output
  (print the-table)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: (("a" 1) ("b" 5) ("c" 100))
```

Looking at the messages buffer...

```
executing R code block (from-r)...
Wrote /tmp/babel-1755OIV/ob-input-17558YA
(("something1" "something2") hline ("a" 1) ("b" 5) ("c" 100))
executing Emacs-Lisp code block...

(the-table (quote (("a" 1) ("b" 5) ("c" 100))))

Code block evaluation complete.
```

...it's clear to me that the output of the 1st block is the complete table but the second block somehow removes the table header. For clarity:

Complete table: `(("something1" "something2") hline ("a" 1) ("b" 5) ("c" 100))`

Table w/o header: `(("a" 1) ("b" 5) ("c" 100))`

I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `:colnames no` to the second code block. (Org uses `org-babel-disassemble-tables` to take apart a table and this function uses `:colnames` to decide if it needs to strip column names.)

Add `:hlines yes` to keep `hline` too.

I don't have R installed, but this seems to work:

```
#+name: make-table
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results value
'(("something1" "something2") hline ("a" 1) ("b" 5) ("c" 100))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: make-table
| something1 | something2 |
|------------+------------|
| a          |          1 |
| b          |          5 |
| c          |        100 |

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var table=make-table :results output :colnames no
(print table)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: (("something1" "something2") ("a" 1) ("b" 5) ("c" 100))
```